# How can I pass a dict to urlpatterns in Django

Tags: html, django, url, view

I am trying to send data from my web page to urlpattern in Django and then to the view. I know that I can include a dict in my urlpattern path that will be sent to my view:

```
path("edit_page", views.edit_article, {'article':'fake_text'}, name="edit_page")
```

I want to send the dict directly from my webpage. I have been trying:

**urls.py**

```
path("edit_page", views.edit_article, name="edit_page")
```

**html**

```
<a href='{% url 'edit_page' {'article': 'article_test'} %}'>Edit</a>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can't. You should somehow encode the data in the URL. You can not implicitly pass that. You can pass data through the URL, the querystring, the POST data, or cookies, but that is all part of the request.

Answer (score 1):

You typically encode the data in the URL, for example with:

```
path('edit_page/<str:article>/', views.edit_article, name='edit_page'),
```

then you define the view as:

```
def edit_article(request, article):
    # …
```

then the view will be called with the `article` part of the URL path.

In the template you can then "calculate" the URL with:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_page' article='article_test' %}">Edit</a>
```